# Find on different properties on multi subclass

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, querydsl

I have 3 entities `Agent`, `Person` and `Machine`

```
abstract Agent
  Long id

Person extends Agent
  String firstName
  String lastName

Machine extends Agent
   String label
```

I searched for a solution to query all my agents on given parameter `"name"`, which would lookup on `firstName` and `lastName` of `Person`, or on label of `Machine`.

Is it possible with a jpql query?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add to Agent an abstract method getName() which returns the name appropriate for the type?

Comment: Yes, i can update Agent class, but how can i use this method in a jpa query ?

Comment: Like any other JavaBean. I assume JPA uses getters rather than underlying fields.

Comment: Thank you for your help but i found a 'sql-like' solution `select a from Agent a, Person p, Machine m
where (p.id = g.id and (p.lastName like :name or p.firstName like :name) 
or (ma.id = g.id and ma.name like :name)`

Comment: This will work best if you want to be able to match either the first or last name.

Comment: Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I am a little late but since querydsl 3.6.2(which corrected the use of instanceOf), you can do this with java code.

```
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
QAgent qAgent = QAgent.Agent;
builder.or(qAgent.as(QPerson.class).firstName.eq("someFirstName")
.and(qAgent.instanceOf(Person.class));

builder.or(qAgent.as(QMachine.class).label.eq("someLabel")
.and(qAgent.instanceOf(Machine.class));

Page<Agent> agentsPage = agentRepository.findAll(builder);
```

On the downside i would reconsider your class structure, this will result in union queries, if you could use a projection with common properties on the superclass maybe the resulting query would be less expensive.